# I want to get all parent nodes along with its child, using a child id for a given data in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, parent-child, traversal

Here is my sample object, suppose If I give the child id "services/bsf/diamSetting" it should return a string like so "nf-bsf -> bsfConfig -> services/bsf/diamSetting"

```
let arr = [{
  "attr": {
    "id": "nf-bsf",
    "name": "BSF",
    "sequence": 1
  },
  "children": [{
    "attr": {
      "id": "bsfGeneralConfig",
      "name": "General Configurations",
      "sequence": 10
    },
    "children": [{
      "attr": {
        "id": "services/bsf/bsfGlobalCfg",
        "name": "General Settings",
        "topic": "bsf.global.cfg",
        "sequence": 10
      }
    }, {
      "attr": {
        "id": "configurations/bsf/sbiErrorCodes",
        "name": "SBI Error Codes",
        "topic": "bsf.sbi.errorcodes",
        "sequence": 20
      }
    }]
  }, {
    "attr": {
      "id": "services/bsf/conLoggingLevel",
      "name": "Logging Level",
      "topic": "consistent.logging.cfg.topics",
      "sequence": 20
    }
  }, {
    "attr": {
      "id": "bsfServices",
      "name": "Service Configurations",
      "sequence": 30
    },
    "children": [{
      "attr": {
        "id": "services/bsf/managementService",
        "name": "Management Service",
        "topic": "bsf.managementservice",
        "sequence": 10
      }
    }]
  }, {
    "attr": {
      "id": "bsfConfig",
      "name": "Diameter Configurations",
      "sequence": 40
    },
    "children": [{
      "attr": {
        "id": "services/bsf/diamSetting",
        "name": "Settings",
        "topic": "common.diamsetting",
        "sequence": 10
      }
    }, {
      "attr": {
        "id": "configurations/bsf/diamPeerNode",
        "name": "Peer Nodes",
        "topic": "common.public.diampeernode",
        "sequence": 20
      }
    }, {
      "attr": {
        "id": "services/bsf/diamRoutingTable",
        "name": "Routing Table",
        "topic": "common.public.diamroutingtable",
        "sequence": 30
      }
    }, {
      "attr": {
        "id": "configurations/bsf/diamLoadShedding",
        "name": "Load Shedding Profiles",
        "topic": "common.public.diamloadshedding",
        "sequence": 40
      }
    }, {
      "attr": {
        "id": "configurations/bsf/diamMessagePriority",
        "name": "Message Priority Profiles",
        "topic": "common.public.diammessagepriority",
        "sequence": 50
      }
    }]
  }, {
    "attr": {
      "id": "bsf-sessionViewer",
      "name": "Session Viewer",
      "sequence": 50
    }
  }, {
    "attr": {
      "id": "administration",
      "name": "Administration",
      "sequence": 60
    },
    "children": [{
      "attr": {
        "id": "bsfBulkExportImport",
        "name": "Export & Import",
        "sequence": 10
      }
    }]
  }]
}];
```

I have tried the following to traverse, i either get undefined or some wrong path. i don't even get child node with this, and this will be traversed in a reverse order.

```
var parent = [];
const findParent = (arr, id) => {
        for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
          if(arr[i].attr.id == id) {
            return parent;
          } else if (arr[i].children && arr[i].children.length) {
            parent.push(arr[i].attr.id);
            findParent(arr[i].children, id)
          }
        }
      };
let x = findParent(arr, "services/bsf/diamSetting");
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `parent` variable outside of the function will break the recursion because each level of recursion shares a common varaible, meaning result of one recursion may overwrite the previous result of another recursion.

You should instead make the `parent` variable something private to the `findParent` function itself so that each recursion will create its own array and modify/returns it.

Here's a revised code that make use of a third argument `hierarchy` that functions the same as your `parent`, but private to each function call ([closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)):

```js
const arr = [ { "attr": { "id": "nf-bsf", "name": "BSF", "sequence": 1 }, "children": [ { "attr": { "id": "bsfGeneralConfig", "name": "General Configurations", "sequence": 10 }, "children": [ { "attr": { "id": "services/bsf/bsfGlobalCfg", "name": "General Settings", "topic" : "bsf.global.cfg", "sequence": 10 } }, { "attr": { "id": "configurations/bsf/sbiErrorCodes", "name": "SBI Error Codes", "topic" : "bsf.sbi.errorcodes", "sequence": 20 } } ] }, { "attr": { "id": "services/bsf/conLoggingLevel", "name": "Logging Level", "topic": "consistent.logging.cfg.topics", "sequence": 20 } }, { "attr": { "id": "bsfServices", "name": "Service Configurations", "sequence": 30 }, "children": [ { "attr": { "id": "services/bsf/managementService", "name": "Management Service", "topic": "bsf.managementservice", "sequence": 10 } } ] }, { "attr": { "id": "bsfConfig", "name": "Diameter Configurations", "sequence": 40 }, "children": [ { "attr": { "id": "services/bsf/diamSetting", "name": "Settings", "topic": "common.diamsetting", "sequence": 10 } }, { "attr": { "id": "configurations/bsf/diamPeerNode", "name": "Peer Nodes", "topic": "common.public.diampeernode", "sequence": 20 } }, { "attr": { "id": "services/bsf/diamRoutingTable", "name": "Routing Table", "topic": "common.public.diamroutingtable", "sequence": 30 } }, { "attr": { "id": "configurations/bsf/diamLoadShedding", "name": "Load Shedding Profiles", "topic": "common.public.diamloadshedding", "sequence": 40 } }, { "attr": { "id": "configurations/bsf/diamMessagePriority", "name": "Message Priority Profiles", "topic": "common.public.diammessagepriority", "sequence": 50 } } ] }, { "attr": { "id": "bsf-sessionViewer", "name": "Session Viewer", "sequence": 50 } }, { "attr": { "id": "administration", "name": "Administration", "sequence": 60 }, "children": [ { "attr": { "id": "bsfBulkExportImport", "name": "Export & Import", "sequence": 10 } } ] } ] } ];

const findParent = (
  arr,
  id,
  hierarchy = []  // Use an array here to store parents instead of using an external variable.
) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    // If id is found, push it to the result array, stop the loop, then return the result.
    if (arr[i].attr.id === id){
      hierarchy.push(arr[i].attr.id);
      return hierarchy;
    }
    
    // If id is not found, proceed to its children
    if (arr[i].children && arr[i].children.length){
      const childResult = findParent(
        arr[i].children,
        id,
        [...hierarchy, arr[i].attr.id]  // Pass the found parents so far to its child recursion.
      );
      
      // Only stop the loop and return the result if id is found in child.
      if (childResult){
        return childResult;
      }
    }
    
    // Proceed to the next loop if id is not found in current item AND its offspring children.
  }

  // Return null if id is not found in this branch.
  return null;
};

let x = findParent(arr, "services/bsf/diamSetting");

console.log(x && x.join(' -> '));
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `parent` array breaks function encapsulation, creating multiple issues:

- It's never popped when a path turns out to be an incorrect one, leading to extra data. This array keeps track of all visited nodes rather than the specific path to the target node.
- The function isn't idempotent; after multiple calls, `parent` may have stale information from a previous traversal.
- If this global data name changes, the function breaks. Functions should be able to withstand refactors outside of their scope.

Here's an approach that addresses these problems. I'm using a closure to keep the result array scoped locally to its function, `pop` to undo every `push` that didn't wind up leading to the target, and `some` to bail out from the search and start unwinding the call stack as soon as the target is found.

```js
const tree = [ { "attr": { "id": "nf-bsf", "name": "BSF", "sequence": 1 }, "children": [ { "attr": { "id": "bsfGeneralConfig", "name": "General Configurations", "sequence": 10 }, "children": [ { "attr": { "id": "services/bsf/bsfGlobalCfg", "name": "General Settings", "topic" : "bsf.global.cfg", "sequence": 10 } }, { "attr": { "id": "configurations/bsf/sbiErrorCodes", "name": "SBI Error Codes", "topic" : "bsf.sbi.errorcodes", "sequence": 20 } } ] }, { "attr": { "id": "services/bsf/conLoggingLevel", "name": "Logging Level", "topic": "consistent.logging.cfg.topics", "sequence": 20 } }, { "attr": { "id": "bsfServices", "name": "Service Configurations", "sequence": 30 }, "children": [ { "attr": { "id": "services/bsf/managementService", "name": "Management Service", "topic": "bsf.managementservice", "sequence": 10 } } ] }, { "attr": { "id": "bsfConfig", "name": "Diameter Configurations", "sequence": 40 }, "children": [ { "attr": { "id": "services/bsf/diamSetting", "name": "Settings", "topic": "common.diamsetting", "sequence": 10 } }, { "attr": { "id": "configurations/bsf/diamPeerNode", "name": "Peer Nodes", "topic": "common.public.diampeernode", "sequence": 20 } }, { "attr": { "id": "services/bsf/diamRoutingTable", "name": "Routing Table", "topic": "common.public.diamroutingtable", "sequence": 30 } }, { "attr": { "id": "configurations/bsf/diamLoadShedding", "name": "Load Shedding Profiles", "topic": "common.public.diamloadshedding", "sequence": 40 } }, { "attr": { "id": "configurations/bsf/diamMessagePriority", "name": "Message Priority Profiles", "topic": "common.public.diammessagepriority", "sequence": 50 } } ] }, { "attr": { "id": "bsf-sessionViewer", "name": "Session Viewer", "sequence": 50 } }, { "attr": { "id": "administration", "name": "Administration", "sequence": 60 }, "children": [ { "attr": { "id": "bsfBulkExportImport", "name": "Export & Import", "sequence": 10 } } ] } ] } ];
 
const findPath = (children, targetId) => {
  const path = [];
  (function search(children) {
    return children?.some(child => {
      path.push(child.attr.id);
      
      if (child.attr.id === targetId || search(child.children)) {
        return true;
      }
      
      path.pop();
    });
  })(children);
  return path;
};

const path = findPath(tree, "services/bsf/diamSetting");
console.log(path.join(" -> "));
```